# JavaScript code doesn't run when I write it one way but does when i modify it a bit

Tags: javascript

can someone guide me as to why my code doesn't run when I write it one way but does run when I modify it a bit?
PS I am writing a simple JavaScript code that will display messages in console based on the variable.
Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
var age = "What is your age?";

prompt(age); 

if(age < 18) {
 console.log("you cant enter");
}

else if(age < 21) {
 console.log("you can enter but cannot drink");
}

else {
 console.log("Your can enter and drink!!");
}
```

however when I write the code this way(copied below), it works. Can someone explain me what i am doing wrong here?

```
var age = prompt("What is your age?");

if(age < 18) {
 console.log("you can not enter");
}

else if(age < 21) {
 console.log("you can enter but cannot drink");
}

else {
 console.log("Your can enter and drink!!");
}
```

Comment: You never saved the result from `prompt()` in the first one, `prompt` doesn't modify a variable passed to it

Comment: you miss the assignment of the input.

Comment: `age = "What is your age?"` through out the code in the first part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not save the result from `prompt` in the first snippet.

```
var age = "What is your age?";

prompt(age); 

// at his point "age" has the value "What is your age?" and you check if age is smaller than < 18 and this is impossible
if(age < 18) {
 console.log("you cant enter");
}

....
```

All in all the issue is that you tried to check if a string is smaller than an int